# Do all rigorous proofs of Euler's product for $\zeta (s)$ use infinitude of primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

There are two proofs of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}=\prod_{p \text{ prime}}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}},\quad \Re (s)\gt 1$$
which I'm aware of. I'll call the first one the **Sieve proof** and the second one will be the **Factorization proof**. Both of them use infinitude of primes (at least I think so).

1. Sieve proof

   By sieving, we see that for every prime $q$
   $$\left(\prod_{p\,\text{prime}\le q}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s} \right) \right) \zeta (s)=\sum_{n;2,3,\ldots ,q\,\nmid\, n}\frac{1}{n^s},\quad \Re (s)\gt 1$$
   where the sum is over all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that are not divisible by the primes from $2$ to $q$. Choosing $r\gt 1$ such that $|s|\gt r$ gives
   $$\begin{align}\left|\left(\prod_{p \text{ prime}\le q}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\right)\zeta (s)-1\right|&=\left|\sum_{n;n\ne 1 \& 2,3,\ldots q,\,\nmid\, n}\frac{1}{n^s}\right|\\
   &\le \sum_{n;n\ne 1 \& 2,3,\ldots q,\\,\nmid\, n}\frac{1}{n^r}\\
   &\le \sum_{n=q}^\infty \frac{1}{n^r},\quad \Re (s)\gt 1.\end{align}$$
   **Because of infinitude of primes**, we can let $q\to\infty$, and by Cauchy's criterion for series $\lim_{q\to\infty}\sum_{n=q}^\infty \frac{1}{n^r}=0$, so
   $$\left(\prod_{p\,\text{prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\right)\zeta (s)=1,\quad \Re (s)\gt 1.$$
2. Factorization proof (this proof is taken from *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function* by Titchmarsh)

   We have
   $$\prod_{p\le P}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}+\frac{1}{p^{2s}}+\cdots\right)=1+\frac{1}{n_1^s}+\frac{1}{n_2^s}+\cdots$$
   where $n_1,n_2,\ldots$ are those integers none of whose prime factors exceed $P$. It follows that
   $$\begin{align}\left|\zeta (s)-\prod_{p\le P}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\right|&=\left|\zeta (s)-1-\frac{1}{n_1^s}-\frac{1}{n_2^s}-\cdots\right|\\
   &\le \frac{1}{(P+1)^{\Re (s)}}+\frac{1}{(P+2)^{\Re (s)}}+\cdots\end{align}$$
   This tends to $0$ as $P\to\infty$ (again **using infinitude of primes**) if $\Re (s)\gt 1$ and the product formula follows.

In [their comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674095/proof-of-eulers-product-for-zeta-s-without-using-infinitude-of-primes#comment9880111_4674095) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674095/proof-of-eulers-product-for-zeta-s-without-using-infinitude-of-primes) the user J.G. commented that the proofs actually don't use infinitude of primes (which he didn't explain – so I'm very confused and I'm writing this question) and his comments contradict a textbook proof by Amann and Escher (see a [related question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165001/zeta-function-product-in-amann-and-escher)) and a [Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Another_proof)  – notice "up to some **prime number limit** $q$".

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746532/proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-by-eulers-product-formula-is-circular) because the OP there fails to distinguish between the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and infinitude of primes.

No one answered on MSE so I'm posting here.

Comment: Those proofs don't use an infinitude of primes. The convergence of the product became trivial if there are only finitely many primes. By taking $q$  (or $P$)  larger than all primes you got an exact formula with the difference 0. Neither $q$ nor $P$ has to be prime.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin Are you suggesting the following? Suppose we don't know whether the number of primes is infinite. We first assume that the number of primes is finite, prove the theorem; then we suppose that the number of primes is infinite and prove the theorem; therefore the theorem is independent of the infinitude of primes?

Comment: @OlegEroshkin This reminds me of Littlewood's proof that $\pi (x)-\operatorname{li} (x)$ changes sign infinitely many times. Littlewood's proof is divided into two cases: the RH is assumed false (about half a page) and the RH is assumed true (about a dozen pages).

Comment: This is not really like Littlewood's proof. Here the main technical issue is the convergence of the infinite product and rigorous verification of the formal manipulations with an infinite product and an infinite series. All that became trivial if the product is finite. So the proof is the same, but technical steps are required only if there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: Just to re-emphasise @OlegEroshkin's comment: this is **really not like** Littlewood's proof. (GH at MO's answer below indicates why)

Comment: @Vestoo I wonder if this way of phrasing it will help you: The proof *avoids assuming that there are finitely many primes*. Avoiding assuming that something is finite is not at all the same as assuming that it is infinite.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither proof uses the infinitude of primes. Here is why ($p$ will always denote a prime number).

1. Sieve proof.

Proceed as you indicated, but don't assume that $q$ is prime. We still have that
$$\left|\left(\prod_{p\le q}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\right)\zeta (s)-1\right|=\left|\sum_{\substack{n>1\\\forall p:\ p\mid n\ \Rightarrow\  p>q}}\frac{1}{n^s}\right|
\le \sum_{n>q}\frac{1}{n^{\Re(s)}},\qquad \Re (s)\gt 1.$$
The right-hand side tends to zero as $q\to\infty$, done.

2. Factorization proof

Proceed as you indicated, and recall that
$$\left|\zeta (s)-\prod_{p\le P}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\right|
=\left|\sum_{\exists p:\ p\mid n\ \&\  p>P}\frac{1}{n^s}\right|
\le \sum_{n>P}\frac{1}{n^{\Re(s)}},\qquad \Re (s)\gt 1.$$
The right-hand side tends to zero as $P\to\infty$, done.

Comment: _Neither proof uses the infinitude of primes._ Maybe it's more accurate to say that both proofs _can be written_ in a way that avoids using the infinitude of primes. In practice, even if they can in principle be written that way (as you have shown), from the point of view of a textbook author it's pedagogically clearer to write them in a way that _does_ assume the infinitude of primes. Therefore the typical writeup of the proofs you'll find in a textbook actually does make that assumption (at least implicitly).

Comment: @DanRomik Thanks for your comment. I disagree with those textbooks, and I would write the proofs as indicated above. In fact it is a far reaching thought (going back to Euler) that the infinitude of primes *follows* from the Euler product decomposition, because $\zeta(s)$ blows up as $s\to 1+$. Elaborating on this thought leads to Mertens' theorems, and ultimately to the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: When proving the infinitude of the primes from divergence of $\sum_p 1/p$, one is going to assume there are finitely many primes, which makes it simpler to justify the expansion of $\prod_p 1/(1-1/p^s)$ into a series. (Euler simply took $s = 1$ right from the start).  I would not necessarily write the upper bounds as $q$ or $P$, but as $x$, so as not to suggest by the choice of letters that the cutoffs are at prime numbers.

Comment: @KConrad The divergence of $\sum_p 1/p$ is already an "advanced version". If there are only finitely many Euler factors, then $\zeta(s)$ has a finite limit as $s\to 1+$, while it doesn't. I agree that $q$ and $P$ are not the best letters for the cut-off.  I copied them from the original post intentionally.

Comment: @GHfromMO Indeed, even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euler's_proof) regards the product formula as furnishing a proof of the infinitude of primes.

Answer (score 4):

An infinite product need not have infinitely many terms different from $1$, just as an infinite series need not have infinitely many terms different from $0$. When proving a convergence test for an infinite series, typically no step in the proof of the convergence test requires the series to have infinitely many nonzero terms (but the tests are trivial if the sum has finitely many nonzero terms). An exception is the alternating series test as presented in a calculus course (edit: what I had in mind here is what students may see occurring in all examples for that convergence test, namely a series $b_1 - b_2 + b_3 - b_4 + \cdots$ where $b_n > 0$ and $b_n > b_{n+1}$).

Here is a theorem on expanding out an infinite product into a series.

**Theorem**.
*Let $\{z_n\}$ be complex numbers with $|z_n| \leq 1 - \varepsilon$ for some positive $\varepsilon$ $($which is independent of $n)$ and $\sum |z_n|$ convergent.*

*a$)$ The infinite product
$\prod_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{1-z_n} :=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}
\prod_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{1-z_n}$ converges to a nonzero number.*

*b$)$ The infinite product in (a) satisfies generalized commutativity
(i.e., every rearrangement of factors gives the same product) and
generalized associativity for products.*

*c$)$ The product $\prod_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{1-z_n} = 
\prod_{n \geq 1} (1 + z_n + z_n^2 + \dots)$ has a series expansion
by collecting terms in the expected manner:
$$
\prod_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{1 - z_n} = 
1 + \sum_{r \geq 1}\sum_{\substack{k_1,\dots,k_r \geq 1 \\ 1 < i_1 < \dots < i_r}}
z_{i_1}^{k_1}\cdots z_{i_r}^{k_r}, 
$$
and the iterated series converges absolutely. $($That is, $\sum_r \sum |z_{i_1}^{k_1}\cdots z_{i_r}^{k_r}| < \infty$.$)$*

This theorem does not require that the terms in the product are infinitely often different from $1$: perhaps $z_n = 0$ for all large $n$, making the product have finitely many terms different from $1$.

For a prime number $p$ and ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$,
$|1/p^s| < 1/2$, so we can apply the theorem with $\varepsilon = 1/2$, $z_n = 1/p_n^s$ for $p_n$ being the $n$th prime and, if there are just $N$ primes, $z_n = 0$ for $n > N$. This way of being careful in applying the above theorem to the Euler product of the zeta-function suggests that it might be pedagogically convenient to show that there are infinitely many primes (by Euler's method or by other methods) before justifying the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$ as an identity.

Comment: I don't think the Leibniz criterion for alternating series is an exception. It says that $\sum (-1)^n b_n$ converges if $b_n\ge 0$ decreases and $b_n\to 0$. This is satisfied if $b_n=0$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling  you're right. I added an edit to indicate what I was thinking about: a weaker version of that test that fits all the examples that a student is likely to encounter in a calculus course.